# Why do I start at privilege level 1 when logging into a Cisco ASA 5510?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, ios

I have created a **test** user that is set to **privilege 15** in the config:

```
username test password **************** encrypted privilege 15
```

When I log in to the ASA 5510 I am in **privilege 1** according to **sh curpriv**:

```
login as: test
test@192.168.1.253's password:
Type help or '?' for a list of available commands.
asa> sh curpriv
Username : test
Current privilege level : 1
Current Mode/s : P_UNPR
```

Attempting **enable** fails even though I know I have the correct enable password:

```
asa> en
Password: *************************
Password: *************************
Password: *************************
Access denied.
```

Logging in from unprivileged puts me on **privilege 15** and I can do as a please:

```
asa> login
Username : test
Pasword: *************************
asa> sh curpriv
Current privilege level : 15
Current Mode/s : P_PRIV
asa>
```

The only thing I can track this to is a configuration change I made where I removed a VPN user we no longer needed.

Why do I start at privilege level 1 when logging into a Cisco ASA 5510?

Comment: How are youconnecting? Telnet? SSH? I'm thinking perhaps maybe if you're using telnet (unsecure) it won't let you go to enable mode?

Comment: The same behavior happens to me with a SSH connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of 2011.11.28 the accepted answer, while correct in some cases, is not accurate in others.

The ASA uses a slightly different model than traditional IOS routers and this where some of the confusion sits.  The second piece is whether or not `aaa authentication enable console LOCAL` is configured.

***Scenario 1 - Enable Authentication Not Configured***

Relevant ASA config

```
enable password enablepass1
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
username user1 password pass1 privilege 15
```

Results

```
login as: user1
user1@ASA's password: pass1
ASA> enable
Password: enablepass1
ASA#
```

If enable authentication is not configured, a user with privilege 15 must still use the enable password to enter privileged exec mode if entering privileged exec mode through `enable`.

***Scenario 2 - Enable Authentication Not Configured but using*** `login`

Relevant ASA config

```
enable password enablepass1
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
username user1 password pass1 privilege 15
```

Results

```
login as: user1
user1@ASA's password: pass1
ASA> login
Username: user1
Password: pass1
ASA#
```

If enable authentication is not configured, a user with privilege 15 can use the `login` command to enter privileged exec mode without knowing or using the enable password.

***Scenario 3 - Enable Authentication Configured***

Relevant ASA config

```
enable password enablepass1
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
aaa authentication enable console LOCAL
username user1 password pass1 privilege 15
```

Results

```
login as: user1
user1@ASA's password: pass1
ASA> enable
Password: enablepass1
Password: pass1
ASA#
```

If enable authentication is configured, a user with privilege 15 can use `login` or `enable` to gain access to privileged exec mode.  If using `enable`, the password required will be the user password and not the enable password.

Answer (score 4):

You can login directly in enable mode if your privilege level allows it.

I am running asa916-k8.bin on 5510

The command is *aaa authorization exec LOCAL auto-enable*

Ravi L

Comment: This was added in ASA Version 9.1(5) which was released in March 2014.  It certainly works now, but wouldn't have then. Thank you for sharing this.

Answer (score 3):

I was confused by this as well but it turns out you just have to enter the password twice.

```
user test pass rootbeer priv 15
```

The user test will login and then when prompted for the enable password the user will enter rootbeer

Comment: Thank you very much :)  That is exactly what I was missing.

Comment: @evolvd The "enter the password twice" is contingent on differing scenarios.  I have attempted to explain the scenarios with examples in an answer.